# How to identify product model in Android app on ARC (Build.model is n/a)?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

Android apps can get product information by reading BUILD.MANUFACTURER and BUILD.MODEL, but when running on ARC (chrome) these are always "chromium" and "App Runtime for Chrome".

Motivation: It is useful for apps which a person uses across multiple devices to be able to identify the model of device the person is using, so you can eg. tell them that some data or action came from their "Nexus 7", or their "Acer Chromebook C910". It is also useful when trying to resolve an obscure issue, to know what product(s) it is occurring on.  As well, though this isn't recommended, sometimes it is useful to identify a model for special handling of that device's characteristics.

In theory it would be possible to take a hash of some static hardware characteristics and use this as a signature for a product, but I think this would be difficult to get right.  If anyone has done this I would be interested to know what api's they used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently any substitute for BUILD.MANUFACTURER and BUILD.MODEL on ARC.

I think it should be technically possible - I know this information is available to Windows applications, and I believe it comes from the BIOS, so in theory I think it could also be available on Mac, Linux, and Chrome OS.

I submitted this as a Chromium [issue here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477403).