# How does ANDROID_ID on ARC (Chrome) differ from Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

On Android, the ANDROID_ID is constant for a user profile on a device (see [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408349/implications-of-android-multiple-user-support-new-in-4-2-for-server-side-data)).  This does not appear to be the case on ARC, but ARC is very new and hopefully this will change.

It is also worth noting - in regards to device identification with ARC - that the Android serial # is not available on ARC, that WiFi MAC address is not currently available (yes, I've seen people talk about using this for device id), and [product model information is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655597/how-to-identify-product-model-in-android-app-on-arc-build-model-is-n-a).

Motivation: I know it is not now recommended, but I think a lot of apps use the ANDROID_ID to identify devices in their server database.

The behavior of ANDROID_ID on Android means that, if a user uninstalls your app and then re-installs it, you would know and could eg. re-sync their data to the device.  And if a user installs two apps of your apps, you know they are on the same device (and user profile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience - using ARC runtime 42.4410.288.23 on Chrome 41.0.2272.118 m (stable) on Windows - a new ANDROID_ID is generated for every app install.

So, for example, if you uninstall your app and then re-install it, it will see a new ANDROID_ID.

I should test this on a Chromebook, since that is the only platform supported for deployment at this time, but I don't have a Chromebook available.

Comment: This is what happens.